# Python input validation for both integer and string

Tags: python, input

I'm new in programming and I have an issue when doing the input validation.
My program requires to input number from 1 to 10 or the letter `y` but it seems that I cannot do an error handler for this.

```
def checkingInput():
    while True:
        try:
            a = input()
            if 10 >= a >= 1 or a == 'y':
                return value
            else:
                print('Invalid input!')
        except NameError:
            print('Name error!Please try again!')
        except SyntaxError:
            print('Syntax Error!Please try again!')
```

Comment: I presume you are using python 3 due to the `print()` but could you please confirm that?

Comment: `SyntaxError` is not an exception that normally happens at runtime.

Comment: I think you want `ValueError` instead of `SyntaxError`. Also you can't compare `ints` with `strings` so you should change your line to `if a == 'y' or 1 <= int(a) <= 10`

Comment: Also, if this is python 3 you do not need to catch NameError either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as jamylak suggested change the if condition to :

```
if a == 'y' or 1 <= int(a) <= 10:
```

program:

```
def checkingInput():
    while True:
        try:
            a = input('enter')
            if a == 'y' or 1 <= int(a) <= 10:
                return a
            else:
                print('Invalid input!')
        except ValueError:
            print('Value error! Please try again!')
```

Comment: doesn't work if `a` is `'y'` since `if` statement checks conditions from left to right and won't be able to convert `'y'` to `int`. Do this instead: `if a == 'y' or 1 <= int(a) <= 10`

Comment: @jamylak Thanks, I really didn't knew that `If` uses left to right checking.

Comment: +1 Also i can't tell if that is sarcasm or not... If it is I'm sorry but I just thought it was worth explaining for other people reading this.

Comment: @jamylak no that isn't sarcasm, it was helpful.

Comment: As an aside: proper style dictates a name of `check_input` - the punctuation (all lowercase with an underscore in between) is the preference of the Python community, but all programmers would prefer the name `check` over `checking`: since the function **does something**, give it a name that's imperative, rather than descriptive.